# Le Petit Prince and the public domain status in France

Tags: copyright, public-domain, france

Trying to reply in this [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31211/dual-lingual-books-post-a-level), I found this interesting link:
https://www.communia-association.org/2015/01/23/the-little-prince-almost-in-the-public-domain/

This is a 2016 article talking about the public domain status of *Le Petit Prince* in particular and the public domain harmonisation in general. An excerpt follows:

> If you know a bit about the rules for determining when a work goes out
>   of copyright, we can assume that on 1st January 2015 “The Little
>   Prince” became part of the public domain. This is because in France
>   copyright lasts for 70 years after the death of the author. And since
>   Saint-Exupéry died in 1944, this would put “The Little Prince” into
>   the public domain in France.
>
> However, the harmonization of the duration of copyright is not
>   uniform. In France, works of authors who died for France during the
>   First and Second World Wars benefit from additional copyright
>   protection. Copyright for works created by these authors is extended
>   for an additional 30 years to compensate for the losses and
>   difficulties in the commercial exploitation of their works during the
>   war.
>
> Beginning this year, “The Little Prince” is in the public domain
>   almost everywhere in Europe. But in France, the novel will pass into
>   the public domain sometime between 1 May 2033 and 1 January 2045,
>   depending on your interpretations of the rules! Interestingly,
>   Canadians have been freely using “The Little Prince” for the last 20
>   years, as copyright expires there 50 years after the death of the
>   creator.

My question is what is the current status of the public domain in France. Having found the text of *Le Petit Prince* available [online](https://www.ebooksgratuits.com/html/st_exupery_le_petit_prince.html) (see also [here](http://www.saintexupery-domainepublic.be/?p=66)), does that mean the aforementioned French Law has been changed since 2016?

Comment: What makes you think that the law has changed? The sites may not be hosted in France, or they may be breaking the law.

Comment: Paraphrased question: "Having found [something] online, does that mean that [it is legal]?" - No.